# R caret use custom probability threshold during cross validation

Tags: r, svm, cross-validation, r-caret

I'm training a SVM using the cross validation method in caret on data with a high class imbalance. I've made a custom `summaryFunction` that maximises the F-measure and using `classProbs=TRUE` I've found an optimal class probability threshold that further maximises the F-measure.

Now I'd like to use this threshold during cross validation but I can't figure out how. The only thing I can think of is re-labeling the prediction column in the `summaryFunction`, before calculating the F-measure, using my custom threshold and the probabilities from `classProbs=TRUE`, but I feel like this would be less effective than actually changing the threshold.

Is there a way to actually change the threshold and if not would this re-labeling be effective?

Comment: [check this out](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/thresholder)

Comment: @missuse Does this not find the optimal threshold after training instead of during cross validation?